# Reformat a long file using awk/sed

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, grep

I have a very long file. The contents of the file are like:

```
myserver1
kernel_version
os

myserver2
kernel_version
os

myserver3
kernel_version
os
...
```

There are more than 10.000 entries and 3 entries for each host. Hostname, kernel_version and OS version.

I would like to have an output like:

```
myserver1, kernel_version, os
myserver2, kernel_version, os
myserver3, kernel_version, os
...
```

instead. So what is the best awk/sed command to provide this output?

Comment: it is required that you add your own attempts to solve to the question... like I could see in questions you've asked in the past...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With sed:

```
$ sed '/^$/d;N;N;s/\n/, /g' infile                                  
myserver1, kernel_version, os                              
myserver2, kernel_version, os                              
myserver3, kernel_version, os
```

This works as follows:

```
/^$/d       # Delete line if empty (skips rest of commands)
N           # Append second line to pattern space
N           # Append third line to pattern space
s/\n/, /g   # Replace newlines by comma and a blank
```

If you want the criterion for the line to be skipped not be "empty line" but its line number (4, 8, 12...), you can replace the first command (this is a GNU extension):

```
sed '4~4d;N;N;s/\n/, /g' infile
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `paste`:

```
paste -d ',,\0' - - - - <file
```

Comment: It's worth noting this works also for non-blank "separator" lines.

Comment: This is quite elegant, but notice that it doesn't actually skip the blank line, it appends it to each record.

Comment: You might use `paste -sd',,\0\n' file` instead, however there would still not be any white space separating the `,`'s

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="";OFS=", "} {print $1,$2,$3}' data.txt
```

defining record separator as empty line with output field separator (`OFS`) as `", "`

You can also use :

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="";OFS=", "} {$1=$1; print $0}' data.txt
```

`$1=$1` forces the record to be reconstituted, see [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Changing-Fields)

Comment: First  command display only attributes for first host. Like:

   myserver1, kernel_version, os

But not the other hosts.

Second one, it display all entries in a single line like:

    myserver1, kernel_version, os, myserver2, kernel_version, os, myserver3, kernel version, os

Comment: @JavaRed in that case you don't have an empty line between the entries and the input sample you showed in question is wrong... and a simple `pr -3ats', ' data.txt` would work for you

Answer (score 0):

While AWK/SED could help you perform this task, a better way would be to use Python, assuming that the *NIX system you are working on has it installed to process this data.

You could use the following in python to process this quite easily:

```py
import csv

output_file = csv.writer(open("/path/to/output/file","w"))

column_num = 3 # number of columns in your end-state data
with open("</path/to/your/input/file>","r") as input:
  row = []
  iteration_counter = 0
  for line in input:
    iteration_counter += 1
    stripped = line.strip() # to remove the newlines (\n)
    if iteration_counter <= column_num:
      row.append(stripped)
    else:
      iteration_counter = 0 # reset the counter to 0
      output_writer.writerow(row) # output the list as a csv row
      row = [] # clear the row list to nothing
      iteration_counter += 1
      row.append(stripped)
```